# Temperature module in aeris weather framework

Tags: weather, temperature

I would like to display temperature in Celsius and not by default Fahrenheit using the following code in aeris weather framework.

```
var aerisMapBuilder = new aeris.interactive.MapAppBuilder({
    apiId:'key1',
    apiSecret:'key2',
    el: '#map-canvas',
    modules: {
        map: {
            zoom: 9,
            center: [37.6436,22.4918],
            scrollZoom: true,
        },
        geosearch: {
            geolocate: true
        },
        localWeather: {
            showOnInit: true
        },
        mapControls: {
            expandOnInit: false,
            groups: ['Points']
        },
       layers: {
            objects: [
                {
                    type: 'SatelliteGlobal',
                    selected: true,
                    opacity: .90

                }

            ]
        } 
    }
});
```

Any idea would help me a lot!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation suggests setting the local units. Reference 1:  [Configuration Options](https://www.aerisweather.com/support/docs/toolkits/aeris-weatherblox/customization/configuration/)

It suggests the following function is used to set the unit types in JS

```
Aeris.wxblox.config.set('unitsType', 'Units.Type.Imperial');
```

Comment: It suggests the following function as you say correctly  but in my case  Aeris.wxblox.config.set('unitsType', 'Units.Type.Metric');                             To be honest i do not know where to place it in my file and thus work successfully. I tried to use it at the end - start but no luck.....

Comment: Did you try aerisMapBuilder.config.set('unitsType', 'Units.Type.Metric') after you have called your function above?

Comment: I have already spoke with them. It is not possible at this moment regarding my own template.